# Finding the average of 5 numbers and N numbers using only While and do while loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop, average, do-while

i am really stuck with this been trying to solve it for quite a time now.
i have to write a program where i should input 5 numbers between 1 to 10 and then calculate the average, USING ONLY WHILE LOOP, but it does not have to exit when the number does not meet the requirement. then, i have to write a variation of the same code but this time you can enter all the numbers you want, and when 0 is entered it has to calculate the average and exit

this is where i have gotten so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i = 1;
    float add;
    float avg;

    do
    {
        printf("enter the number %d:\n", i++);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        add = add + n;
    } while(n > 0 && n < 11);

    avg= (add / 5);

    printf("%.1f", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

it will keep asking for numbers after 5 have been entered. and the average is not right anyways

Comment: Is this what they are teaching in colleges now? God...

Comment: That "prom" has got to be a typo.  I'm substituting "avg" in my head.

Comment: The variable `add` is not initialized. `add = add + n` yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: There are at least 3 kinds of mathematical averages -- which one are you looking for?  The fact that you are being asked for "5" may suggest that we are looking for a moving mean value

Comment: @Soren i mean mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're using `n`as your `while` condition variable, but also as the variable to scan the input. If I start your program by scanning 20, for example, your `while` loop will exit on the first interaction. Use your `i` variable instead and also increment it every time your loop executes.

```
do{
    ...
}while(i <= 5);
```

Second, if you want only numbers between 1 and 10, then you should write a condition for it. For example:

```
printf("enter the number %d:\n", i); //do not increment it here!
scanf("%d",&n); //assuming "n" as your variable to scan
if(n > 0 && n < 11){
    add += n;
    i++; //increment it here instead!
}
```

Third, initialize your variables in order to not get thrash values

```
float add = 0;
float avg = 0;
int i = 1;
```

Finally, assign your result (not mandatory, but since you're using it I'll keep it):

```
avg = add/5.0f
```

and display:

```
printf("%.1f", avg);
```

Comment: Thanks, i understood that perfectly.

Comment: Just another thing that came into my mind reading again your question: if you initialize your `i` variable, for example `i = 1`, you can change your `do-while` loop to a `while` loop: `while(i <= 5)`. Keep in mind that `do-while` loops and `while` loops are not the same thing.